mongoDB installation: How can I fix mongoNetworkError?
I'm trying to install Mongodb community server on macbook air with the new M1 chip following the official mongodb tutorial. However i met this error. How can I fix error 4 and MongoNetworkError?
$ brew services list
Name              Status   User File
mongodb-community error  4 root \~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

$ mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 676bfdd6ff9028d80dc98a5a
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.3.7
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017\

I didn't even find the reason of error 4 through googling. I tried uninstall and intall again and again, it didn't work.
Your experience would be very helpful

Did you check the mongod logfile? Typically at var/log/mongodb/mongod.log. Common problem is the data (dbPath) folder does not exist.

I checked it and No such file or directory is shown. What should I do next?

I am not familiar with apple. Check the files which defines the service. This should show a configuration file. In this configuration file you should find the logfile path. See how it looks on Linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187641/mongodb-systemctl-start-failure-due-to-dbpath-keyfile-path-permission-error/69187822#69187822 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77821318/mongodb-is-in-stopped-state-and-getting-failed-when-trying-to-start/77823929#77823929
